# Is it mandatory to create web application on port 80 for sharepoint hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have installed SharePoint 2013. I have gone through my web portals suggesting there are two ways for working with SharePoint hosted app

1. Create Web Application on port 80. The web application will use the server name as its url
2. Create Web applications without host headers on any port and to create Host Header Site Collections

I dont want to go with powershell to create host header site collection. Because we can not create host header site collection programatically. If I go with first option then I think I must create web application which is listening on port 80. Is it mandatory to create web application on port 80 for sharepoint hosted app ? If I create web application on other than port 80 then does my sharepoint hosted app will work properly ?

Comment: No. You can choose whatever port you want. Host-headers and ports have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @ChristopherW This link expalin about host headers and ports http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx